# Java SQLException separate according to errorcode

Tags: java, try-catch, derby, sqlexception

I need to separate `SQLExceptions` according to `ErrorCode`. I have the following `if` statement in `catch block` but the `else` condition is printed always.

```
catch (SQLException ex) {

      if (ex.getErrorCode() == 28502){
         System.out.println("Username Problem");
      }

      else{
         System.out.println("Other Problem");
      }  

     Logger.getLogger(FirstTimeMainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

}
```

Actually, when I enter unexpected `username` when creating DB, the following `SQLExceptions` are thrown.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database 'myDB', see the next exception for details.
//rest of exception.
Caused by: ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'myDB', see the next exception for details.
//rest of exception.
Caused by: ERROR XBM01: Startup failed due to an exception. See next exception for details
//rest of exception.
Caused by: ERROR 28502: The user name 'AAA.AAA' is not valid.
//rest of exception.
```

But my `catch` is always print `Other Problem`. How can I separate different `SQLExceptions` according to last `ErrorCode`?

Comment: Judging by the exception, it's actually the third chained exception that has that code, so try traversing the chain using `ex.getNextException()`. Loop until that's `null` or you find the desired error code.

Comment: can you just do a System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode())? that can clearly tell you whats the code returned

Comment: @zerocool it returns `40000`

Comment: cool.. compare it with 40000..

Comment: @zerocool I'd guess *any* `Failed to create database` exception will have an error code of 40000, so that won't help differentiate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**--- SOLVED ---**

Thanks for the routed comments for @blm first.

**Trick is;** Other coming `Exceptions` (1st and 2nd) has `String` values in their `SQLState` only numeric value in their `ErrorCode`.

`SQLException` chain 3rd `exception` has `28502` both `SQLState` and `ErrorCode`. This is the difference between 1st and 2nd `Exceptions` i think.

So i have changed my

**Catch Block;**

```
catch (SQLException se) {

      do {

         if(se.getSQLState().equals("28502")){
            System.out.println("Username Problem");
         }

         else{
            System.out.println("Other Problem");
         }  

      } while ((se = se.getNextException()) != null);

}
```

**Output is;**

```
Other Problem
Other Problem
Username Problem
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured out an approach that works for you. You might want to look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6779 and possibly file a related issue describing your scenario and the workaround you had to use, so the Derby team can investigate making this process easier in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you should get the cause exceptions by using the 'getCause()' method of the SqlExeption object that was caught. then, you can cast the result to Exception and check its error code.
check this for more info: [Throwable.getCause()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29)

**Edit:**

```
SQLException temp = ex;
while(temp.getCause() != null)
{
     temp = (Exception)temp.getCause();
}
//  check if temp is SQLException and if it is check ((SQLException)temp).getErrorCode() == whatever you want
```

Comment: `getCause()` returns `ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'myDB', see the next exception for details.` We need follow the chain i think. But how.

Comment: right, and then you should keep calling it till you get to the one with the right status code

Comment: But exact errorcode will always showing last in chain for `SQLExceptions` i dont know.

Comment: This is basically what I was suggesting in my comment on the original post, although I don't know offhand the difference between `getCause()` and `getNextException()`, so try both. :-) Whichever works, the `getErrorCode()` on the last exception should give you the root cause.

Comment: `getErrorCode()` not working for `temp` Should it be `SQLException` ?

Comment: yes, check if it can be cast to SQLException, and if it does, cast it and check its getErrorCode()

Comment: @BlackWhite Maybe, give it a try. `getNextException()` already returns an `SQLException`, so maybe it returns the same as `getCause()` but without requiring the cast?

Comment: Ok i changed the object to `SQLException temp = ex;` and while loop to `temp = (SQLException) temp.getCause();` and if statement is `temp.getErrorCode() == 28502` But this time i dont have any printout :)

Comment: changed it with your fix

Comment: @blm I was try using `getNextException()` method in many ways but i am not succeed.

Comment: Also if i add `System.out.println(temp.getCause());` inside while loop. I receive two times `ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'myDB', see the next exception for details.` And never enter to if or else statement.

Comment: might be you have another exception while casting to SQLException, I would suggest that you debug and check what is the **type** of the root cause exception.

Comment: When we add while loop inside catch block i have not any Logger output or if else statement output. I have set try catch block for while loop. Problem in while loop, it is throw `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException cannot be cast to java.sql.SQLException` But i dont know maybe i use wrong catch mechanism for catch the while loop Exceptions. I was use `catch(Exception es)` for catch the while loop exception.